# android ViewFlipper behaviour

Tags: android, viewflipper

I had flip the View manually via showNext() like this :

```
flipper.showNext();

View current  = flipper.getCurrentView();
current.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE);

// ... some animation to show the view
```

My question is why flipper.showNext() will not show next View on screen before it make the view invisible. (the code make the next view invisible then only show but not show the next view then only become invisible)

The code archived what I want, but I don't know why it behave like this.

Is this becoz of UI thread is not running in sequence ? (if sequence, it should show the view before setting it to invisible)

any idea or better code do to the same thing?

kiwi

Answer (score 0):

Another way to flip the view with animation is to use [3DTransition](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Transition3d.html), You can see an example of it from ApiDemo > Views > Animation > 3D Transition.